# PHP Create List with Replaced characters

Tags: php

I am trying to basically create a list of obscene words for a filter. I wanted to generate the list by creating arrays of characters and their replacements, example. 'A' can be replaced with '4', or "E" with "3".

So basically I have a bunch of arrays for every char in the alphabet with the several different ways to replace it. EG. $e = array( "e" =>"3"); I have an array of obscene words. I need to print all the obscene words and then their variants where the letters match. Example:

Hello
He11o
He1lo
H3llo
H31lo
H311o

Every variation. How would I go about doing this? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: "I have a bunch of arrays for every char in the alphabet with the several different ways to replace it". just to ask for clarification - each character has one and only one possible replacement, right?  And do you have 26 replacements, or don't you bother with some (maybe Q, Z, etc? It seems like you don't change H in your example - maybe you are only changing vowels?)  Hmm, do you want to be fancy and have replacements for upper and lower case?

Comment: Btw, if it's homewrok, please say so - that way we can give you pointers without writing your code for you. If it's not, would you consider using someone else's code? There seems to be plenty out there ... http://www.google.com.sg/search?hl=en&safe=off&q=php+censor+%22obscene+words

But maybe you'd just rather code it yourself as a learning exercise. If so, the more precise your spcification, the better we can help (if you want anything other than just 1 letter => 1 other letter). Thanks

Comment: Filtering obscene words with regexes or word lists, clbuttic! Experience tought me it is almost impossible to try to come up with any system that will not be 'cracked' in seconds by randomly entering some 'safe' characters, spaces, etc., while still getting the message across. By all means, set some alerts on it for moderators, but active moderating and possibly banning will be the only way to keep most profanity at bay if you wish to do so. There's no programmatical silver bullet.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for regular expressions for me.

```
preg_replace('/H[e3][l1]{2}[0o]/i','H****',$textstr);
```